# Apache nutch selenium with firefox

Tags: linux, selenium-chromedriver, nutch, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm trying to crawl websites with Apache nutch 1.14. some of the website are javascript enabled. As per the wiki page of Nutch we need to use selenium plug-in.

I have followed the steps as mentioned. when I start the crawl using Firefox(Geckodriver) or chrome drivers with latest version. I get issues.

With firefox error is

```
FetcherThread 45 fetch of http://online.wsj.com/news/technology failed with: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unable to bind to locking port 7054 within 45000 ms
Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd10cf2c0560f637404c2d96164b67d9d67', time: '2015-10-09 13:08:06'
System info: host: 'Latitude-3480', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.15.0-29-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_171'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
```

With Chrome browser it opens up the chrome instance but after couple of secs that instance will get close throwing this error:

```
INFO  fetcher.Fetcher - -activeThreads=5, spinWaiting=0, fetchQueues.totalSize=231, fetchQueues.getQueueCount=162
2018-08-16 19:19:11,626 ERROR selenium.Http - Failed to get protocol output
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: timeout
  (Session info: chrome=67.0.3396.99)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578700 (2f1ed5f9343c13f73144538f15c00b370eda6706),platform=Linux 4.15.0-29-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 3.04 seconds
Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd10cf2c0560f637404c2d96164b67d9d67', time: '2015-10-09 13:08:06'
System info: host: 'shrayas-Latitude-3480', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.15.0-29-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_171'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{mobileEmulationEnabled=false, hasTouchScreen=false, platform=LINUX, acceptSslCerts=false, goog:chromeOptions={debuggerAddress=localhost:41661}, acceptInsecureCerts=false, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, setWindowRect=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=, applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.41.578700 (2f1ed5f9343c13f73144538f15c00b370eda6706), userDataDir=/tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.0AKw1H}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, version=67.0.3396.99, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, locationContextEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: f620c1ef6e7eb119a0b67e5136f311f6
*** Element info: {Using=tag name, value=body}
    at org.apache.nutch.protocol.selenium.HttpWebClient.getHtmlPage(HttpWebClient.java:204)
    at org.apache.nutch.protocol.selenium.HttpResponse.readPlainContent(HttpResponse.java:244)
    at org.apache.nutch.protocol.selenium.HttpResponse.<init>(HttpResponse.java:168)
    at org.apache.nutch.protocol.selenium.Http.getResponse(Http.java:58)
    at org.apache.nutch.protocol.http.api.HttpBase.getProtocolOutput(HttpBase.java:276)
    at org.apache.nutch.fetcher.FetcherThread.run(FetcherThread.java:342)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: timeout
  (Session info: chrome=67.0.3396.99)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578700 (2f1ed5f9343c13f73144538f15c00b370eda6706),platform=Linux 4.15.0-29-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 3.04 seconds
Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd10cf2c0560f637404c2d96164b67d9d67', time: '2015-10-09 13:08:06'
System info: host: 'Latitude-3480', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.15.0-29-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_171'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
```

And these are the configs I used

```
<property>
  <name>plugin.includes</name>
  <value>protocol-(selenium|http)|urlfilter-(regex|validator)|parse-(html|tika)|index-(basic|anchor)|indexer-solr|scoring-opic|urlnormalizer-(pass|regex|basic)</value>
  <description>Regular expression naming plugin directory names to
  include.  Any plugin not matching this expression is excluded.
  In any case you need at least include the nutch-extensionpoints plugin. By
  default Nutch includes crawling just HTML and plain text via HTTP,
  and basic indexing and search plugins. In order to use HTTPS please enable 
  protocol-httpclient, but be aware of possible intermittent problems with the 
  underlying commons-httpclient library. Set parsefilter-naivebayes for classification based focused crawler.
  </description>
</property>
<property>
  <name>selenium.driver</name>
  <value>firefox</value>
  <description>
    A String value representing the flavour of Selenium 
    WebDriver() to use. Currently the following options
    exist - 'firefox', 'chrome', 'safari', 'opera', 'phantomjs' and 'remote'.
    If 'remote' is used it is essential to also set correct properties for
    'selenium.hub.port', 'selenium.hub.path', 'selenium.hub.host',
    'selenium.hub.protocol', 'selenium.grid.driver' and 'selenium.grid.binary'.
  </description>
</property>
```

Kindly Let me know if theres in solution to this. Or else if I can get any samples how this should work It will help me lot.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hi did you solve this problem? I have the same issue. Many thanks